# Php Collecting Cycles (Garbage Collection)

Tags: php, garbage-collection

i was looking at Php "Garbage Collection". I found it on php.net ([click](http://php.net/manual/de/features.gc.php)).
The problem is english isnt my native language^^
I tried to understand it, but its quiet hard for me.

I understand the things with the "zval" container etc.

But i dont get how the collection cycles works.

It would be very nice, if someone may could explain me, how it works..